# Python Categorizing Dataframe columns based on part of the colomn name

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dictionary

**Reproducible data:**

```
import random
    data = {'test_1_a':random.sample(range(1, 50), 7),
            'test_1_b':random.sample(range(1, 50), 7),
    'test_1_c':random.sample(range(1, 50), 7),
    'test_2_a':random.sample(range(1, 50), 7),
    'test_2_b':random.sample(range(1, 50), 7),
    'test_2_c':random.sample(range(1, 50), 7),
    'test_3_a':random.sample(range(1, 50), 7),
    'test_4_b':random.sample(range(1, 50), 7),
    'test_4_c':random.sample(range(1, 50), 7)}
    df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

**Description:**

I have a data frame similar to the example I gave above with 1000ish columns. The column name format is as following:

test_**number**_**family** so test_1_c would be a number type of 1 and the family of "c"

I want to classify the df by column names of the same "family" type. So my final output needs to be a list of lists of same family values:

**Output example:**

[ [a_familily values], [b_familily values],...]

it would also look like the ***values of columns***:

[ [test_1_a, test_2_a , test_3_a ] , [test_1_b, test_2_b , test_3_b ] , ...]

**What I have:**

```
#### transfers data frame into a sorted dict (by column name) by columns as key
col_names = [ i for (i,j) in df.iteritems() ]
col_vals = [ j for (i,j) in df.iteritems() ]

df_dict = dict(zip(col_names, col_vals))


families = np.unique([ i.split("_")[2] for i in dict1.keys() ])
```

I have classified each column name with its associated value and extracted the unique number of groups I want to have in the final output as "families". I now am seeking help in categorizing the data frame into a length(families) number of lists identical to the output example I have given above.

I hope my explanation has been clear, thank you for your time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's keep track of the different families in a dictionary, the keys being the letters (the families) and the values being lists holding the columns from a certain family.

Since we know that each column ends with a letter related with its family, we can use that as a key in the dictionary.

```py
from collections import defaultdict
families = defaultdict(list)

for col in df.columns:
    families[col[-1]].append(df[col])
```

Now for example, in `families["a"]`, we have:

```
[0    26
 1    13
 2    11
 3    35
 4    43
 5    45
 6    46
 Name: test_1_a, dtype: int64,
 0    10
 1    15
 2    20
 3    43
 4    40
 5    35
 6    22
 Name: test_2_a, dtype: int64,
 0    35
 1    48
 2    38
 3    13
 4     3
 5    10
 6    25
 Name: test_3_a, dtype: int64]
```

We can easily get a per-family dataframe with `concat`.

```
df_a = pd.concat(families["a"], axis=1)
```

Gets us:

```
   test_1_a  test_2_a  test_3_a
0        26        10        35
1        13        15        48
2        11        20        38
3        35        43        13
4        43        40         3
5        45        35        10
6        46        22        25
```

If we were to create a dictionary of dataframes per family,

```
dfs = {f"df_{fam}" : pd.concat(families[fam], axis=1) for fam in families.keys()}
```

Now, the dictionary `dfs` contains:

```
{'df_a':    test_1_a  test_2_a  test_3_a
 0        26        10        35
 1        13        15        48
 2        11        20        38
 3        35        43        13
 4        43        40         3
 5        45        35        10
 6        46        22        25,
 'df_b':    test_1_b  test_2_b  test_4_b
 0        18         4        44
 1        48        43         2
 2        30        21         4
 3        46        12        16
 4        42        14        25
 5        22        24        13
 6        43        40        43,
 'df_c':    test_1_c  test_2_c  test_4_c
 0        25        15         5
 1        36        39        28
 2         6         3        37
 3        22        48        16
 4         2        34        25
 5        39        16        30
 6        32        36         2}
```

Answer (score 1):

What do you think of an approach like that ? Use `pd.wide_to_long` with the result of a long dataframe with splitted columns, one with the whole `classification` like `1_a`, one only with the number, one with the family and their values.

```
df = (pd.wide_to_long(
    df.reset_index(),stubnames='test_',i='index',j='classification',suffix='\d_\w')
      .reset_index()
      .drop('index',axis=1)
      .rename(columns={'test_':'values'}))

df[['number', 'family']] = df['classification'].str.split('_', expand=True)
df = df.reindex(columns=['classification', 'number', 'family', 'values'])

print(df)

   classification number family  values
0             1_a      1      a      29
1             1_a      1      a      46
2             1_a      1      a       2
3             1_a      1      a       6
4             1_a      1      a      16
..            ...    ...    ...     ...
58            4_c      4      c      30
59            4_c      4      c      23
60            4_c      4      c      26
61            4_c      4      c      40
62            4_c      4      c      39
```

Easy to groupby or filter for more analysis.
If you want to get `dicts` or `lists` of specific data, here some examples:

```
filter1 = df.loc[df['classification']=='1_a',:]
filter2 = df.loc[df['number']=='2','values']

filter1.to_dict(orient='list')
Output: 
{'classification': ['1_a', '1_a', '1_a', '1_a', '1_a', '1_a', '1_a'],
 'number': ['1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1'],
 'family': ['a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a'],
 'values': [29, 46, 2, 6, 16, 12, 38]}

filter2.tolist()
Output: 
[8, 2, 43, 9, 5, 30, 28, 26, 25, 49, 3, 1, 47, 44, 16, 9, 8, 15, 24, 36, 1]
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure I understand the question completely; is this what you have in mind:

```py
dict(list(df.groupby(df.columns.str[-1], axis = 1)))

{'a':    test_1_a  test_2_a  test_3_a
 0        20        36        14
 1         4         7        16
 2        28        13        28
 3         3        40         9
 4        38        41         5
 5        34        47        18
 6        49        25        46,
 'b':    test_1_b  test_2_b  test_4_b
 0        35        10        44
 1        46        14        23
 2        26        11        36
 3        17        27         4
 4        13        16        42
 5        20        38         9
 6        41        22        18,
 'c':    test_1_c  test_2_c  test_4_c
 0        22         2        26
 1        42        24         3
 2        15        16        41
 3         7        11        16
 4        40        37        47
 5        38         7        33
 6        39        22        24}
```

This groups the columns on the last letter in the column name.

If this is not what you have in mind, kindly comment and maybe explain a bit better where I misunderstood your intent.

Comment: Hello, yes this is exactly what I want